Undeclared Identifier Error for _exists() Function in Solidity Contract Using OpenZeppelin
Question Body:
I'm developing an ERC721 contract using OpenZeppelin libraries, and I'm encountering an error when calling _exists() in my Solidity contract. The error message is:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
Details:
Solidity version: ^0.8.0
Using OpenZeppelin contracts:

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

Problem: The line that causes the error is:
require(_exists(tokenId), "Token does not exist");
I thought _exists() was available through ERC721 or ERC721Enumerable, but it seems that the function is not being recognized.
Question:
Why is _exists() not being recognized in this context?
How can I properly use _exists() to check if a token ID exists in my contract, or what is an appropriate workaround?

Any guidance or insights would be appreciated!
What I Tried:
I imported ERC721 and ERC721Enumerable from OpenZeppelin and used them as base contracts in my custom contract.
I called the _exists(tokenId) function in a tokenURI() method and other functions to check for the existence of tokens.

What I Expected:
I expected the Solidity compiler to recognize the _exists() function as part of the ERC721 or ERC721Enumerable base contracts, allowing me to check if a token ID exists without issues.
What Actually Happened:
The compiler threw the following error:
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
This occurred for every instance where _exists() was called, suggesting that the function is not available or not recognized in my current contract scope.
